# Removing Glimpse breaks sitecore

Tags: sitecore, iis-7.5, glimpse

I have a sitecore site. I installed Glimpse. I don't really like how it behaves with sitecore. I I installed it. When I go to the site, it is completely broken. I get a 500 error. Totally blank screen. I can even get the code to step into application_start. In IIS I check for configuration errors, but no dice. No error written to event log. If I reinstall glimpse, it all works.

Comment: How did you uninstall Glimpse? By removing the nuget packages? http://kevinobee.github.io/Sitecore.Glimpse/remove-glimpse.html

Comment: Can you post that an answer so I can mark it as the answer? I think... The answer was in that post at least...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed Glimpse using Nuget then you remove it by following the uninstall instructions on the [Removing Sitecore.Glimpse](http://kevinobee.github.io/Sitecore.Glimpse/remove-glimpse.html) page:

> To remove just the Sitecore extension to Glimpse run the following command in the Package Manager Console:
>
> `uninstall-package sitecore.glimpse`
>
> To then completely remove glimpse from your web application run the following commands:
>
> `uninstall-package glimpse.aspnet`
>
> `uninstall-package glimpse`
>
> Note: when uninstalling glimpse.aspnet the following line will need to be added back into the  section.
>
> `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />`

There are additional options listed on that page to Block Access via a Security Policy or simply Disabling Glimpse without removal also.

Comment: For me, the real issue was adding back: <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />